# QuickFixJ session config is null. The SessionSettings InputStream InputStreamReader TokenizerToken produces null

Tags: inputstream, quickfixj

In QuickFixJ the config file is not read, causing session settings to be null, but the initiator still starts, but doesn't connect anywhere. There are no log or store directories produced and no error given.

Using the normal config file loading process set out in the docs, the config file is read under the hood by the `SessionSettings.java` class. It uses the following code:

```
private void load(InputStream inputStream) throws ConfigError {
    try { 
        Properties currentSection = null;
        String currentSectionId = null;
        final Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
        final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        Tokenizer.Token token = tokenizer.getToken(reader);
        while (token != null) {
        ...
```

This is my `inputStream`

[image]

It looks like a good inputStream but the tokenizer is consistently producing `null`.

[image]

There's nothing wrong with the QuickFix config file `FIX.cfg` that I can see. I am using JDK11.

Comment: Could you add your config file?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that my config file was saved with Character Encoding `UTF-8 with BOM` by Notepad which was very unexpected.

[image: TradeWeb]